# How do I use multiple submit buttons with react-final-form?

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

I want to build a form using [react-final-form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form) that has multiple submit buttons, where each submit button sets a different value in the form. Essentially, I want to create a form that looks something like this in rendered HTML:

```html
<form>
  Are you over 18 years old?
  <button type="submit">Yes</button>
  <button type="submit">No</button>
</form>
```

However, I can't figure out how to make react-final-form treat these different submit buttons as setting values in the form. I tried combining component state, `<input type="hidden">`, and `onClick` handlers, like this:

```js
class FormWithMultipleSubmits extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: undefined
  };

  setValue = value => this.setState({ value: value });

  render() {
    return (
      <Form>
        Are you over 18 years old?
        <Field
          name="adult"
          component="input"
          type="hidden"
          value={this.state.value}
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={() => this.setValue(true)}>
          Yes
        </button>
        <button type="submit" onClick={() => this.setValue(false)}>
          No
        </button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

However, that doesn't seem to work -- probably because [the `value` property on the `<Field>` component is only used for checkboxes and radio buttons](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#value-any).

Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction, for how to solve this properly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/18v6pmql1q) that shows how.

Comment: If I have validation on a form, how can I disable validation for just one of these buttons?